# How to set a DTO's property value directly in LINQ select statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Deal all,

Assume I have a XML file and I need to parse it to objects (DTOs). Example:

```
<Root>
  <Item>
    <X>1</X>
    <Y>2</Y>
  <Item>
</Root>
```

And I have a DTO object:

```
public class Item
{
  public int X{get;set;}
  public int Y{get;set;}
  public int Z{get;set;}
}
```

To create a Item object, I need to know X and Y, and I will set Z = X*Y

I use LINQ to parse XML to objects:

```
XDocument reportDoc = XDocument.Load(@"Report.xml");
var query = from item in reportDoc.Element("Root").Descendants()
select new Item()
{
   X = Convert.ToInt32(item.Element("X").Value),
   Y = Convert.ToInt32(item.Element("Y").Value)
   // Z = X*Y -> I can't do this by this statement
};
```

Please help me how to set value to Z property directly in LINQ select statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `let` clause to declare intermediate variables:

```
XDocument reportDoc = XDocument.Load(@"Report.xml");
var query = from item in reportDoc.Element("Root").Descendants()
let x = Convert.ToInt32(ticket.Element("X").Value)
let y = Convert.ToInt32(ticket.Element("Y").Value)
select new Item()
{
   X = x,
   Y = y
   Z = x * y
};
```